# jQuery/Javascript: set border of iframe from inside iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an iframe and I want to set it's border to zero.

But I want to do this from *inside* the iframe, using javascript or jQuery.

How to do this? Many thanks in advance,

Comment: Will the document containing it be on the same origin? Because if not, you'll hit the [SOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), since to remove the border on the `iframe` you have to modify the containing document (at least, as far as I know).

Comment: thanks for the advice. They're on different domains ;(

Comment: @ Eamorr: Ah, well, then my answer below is right, just not very useful to you. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the parent is on a different origin, you can't do it, because access to the parent's content is forbidden by the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

If the parent document is on the same origin, this should do it:

```
(function() {
  var frames = window.parent.document.getElementsByTagName("iframe"),
      index,
      frame;

  for (index = 0; index < frames.length; ++index) {
    frame = frames[index];
    if (frame.contentWindow == window) {
      frame.frameBorder = "none";
    }
  }
})();
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/epebem) | [source of parent](http://jsbin.com/epebem/edit) | [source of frame](http://jsbin.com/obapen/edit)

Note that it's important to use `==` rather than `===` when comparing the `window` properties (unusually, `window` is special).

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by `$(parent.document).find('#myIframe').css('border', 'xxxx');` - But as pointed out by the comment above, both the pages (main one as well as the one shown in the iframe) should be in the same domain - otherwise you'll end up with a security exception because of same origin policy.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you can use parent.$

```
parent.$("iframe").prop("frameborder", 0); // This will change all iframes
parent.$("#IframeID").prop("frameborder", 0); // This will change single iframe
```